# Implementing StrStr()

Tags: c#, strings

This is a naive implementation - I know that there are algorithms like [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

However I was trying to implement it as best as I can.

```
string test = "giladdarmonwhatareyoudoing";
int index = StrStr(test, "are");


//Returns an index to the first occurrence of str2 in str1,
//or a -1 pointer if str2 is not part of str1.

public int StrStr(string test, string strToFind)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        if (test[i] == strToFind[0])
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < strToFind.Length; j++)
            {
                if (test[i + j] != strToFind[j])
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == strToFind.Length)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Algorithm**

- your implementation has some serious **bugs and unexpected behaviour**.

  - If passing `String.Empty` as second parameter, it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`
  - If passing the unique ending part of the first parameter appended by at least one character to the second parameter, it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

    ```
    string test = "giladdarmonwhatareyoudoing";
    int index = StrStr(test, "ng1");
    ```
  - If you are passing `null` as either first or second parameter a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. Here it would be better to throw an `ArgumentNullException` by using a guard clause.

    ```
    if (test == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("test"); }
    if (strToFind == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("strToFind"); }
    ```
- your implementation could be improved by

  - checking if `strToFind.Length > test.Length`
  - checking if `test.Length - i > strToFind.Length`

**Naming**

You shouldn't use hungarian notation. Consider to rename `strToFind` to `searchForm` or `searchArgument`.

**Refactoring**

After extracting the inner loop to a separate method, removing the now unneeded `if (test[i] == strToFind[0])` and implementing the above we will get

```
public int StrStr(string value, string searchArgument)
{
    if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); }
    if (searchArgument == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("searchArgument"); }
    if (searchArgument.Length == 0) { return 0; }

    int searchLength = searchArgument.Length;
    int length = value.Length;

    if (searchLength > length) { return -1; }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (length - i < searchLength) { return -1; }

        if (IsMatchAtIndex(value, searchArgument, i)) { return i; }
    }
    return -1;
}

private bool IsMatchAtIndex(String value, String searchArgument, int startIndex)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < searchArgument.Length; j++)
    {
        if (value[startIndex + j] != searchArgument[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I prefer the above, but you could also add

```
if (length - i < searchLength) { return -1; }
```

inverted as condition to the `for` loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < length && length - i >= searchLength; i++)
{
    if (IsMatchAtIndex(value, searchArgument, i)) { return i; }
}
```

Comment: I used  string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) in the end for user Input great thing to remember to do for next time thanks.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> //Returns an index to the first occurrence of str2 in str1,
> //or a -1 pointer if str2 is not part of str1.
>
> public int StrStr(string test, string strToFind)
> ```

That comment would be much better off as an XML comment, so that client code can see the documentation for the method with IntelliSense:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an index to the first occurrence of str2 in str1,
/// or a -1 pointer if str2 is not part of str1.
/// </summary>
public int StrStr(string test, string strToFind)
```

Another problem, is that the `str1` and `str2` parameters mentioned in the comment, aren't the actual parameter names you're using. You can use `paramref` for that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the index of the first occurrence of <paramref name="test"/> in <paramref name="strToFind"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="test">The input string.</param>
/// <param name="strToFind">The value to find.</param>
/// <returns>Returns -1 if specified value is not found.</returns>
public int StrStr(string test, string strToFind)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb7x2fhw.aspx):

> The `<paramref>` tag gives you a way to indicate that a word in the code comments, for example in a `<summary>` or `<remarks>` block refers to a parameter. The XML file can be processed to format this word in some distinct way, such as with a bold or italic font.

Use the `<returns>` XML tag to specify a function's return value - the `<summary>` tag should simply state what the function does, not cover all possible outcomes.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly minor stuff:

1. You have probably taken the name from the C function but `StrStr` is actually not really a good name. `StartIndexOf` or similar might be better.
2. You could write it as an extensions method to `string` which would result in a nicer calling syntax. It would look like this then:

   ```
   public static int StartIndexOf(this string test, string toFind)
   {
       ....
   }
   ```

   and call it like this:

   ```
   string test = "giladdarmonwhatareyoudoing";
   int index = test.StartIndexOf("are");
   ```